# Cannot position Google +1 button with CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, positioning

I'm having some trouble positioning the Google +1 button on my website. The div is as follows:

```
<div class="g-plusone"></div>
```

The CSS I'm using is pretty simple:

```
.g-plusone
{ 
position: absolute; 
top:95px;
left:715px; 
}
```

Despite what would seem straightforward, it simple does not want to move.

I know for a fact that the div in question is being accessed. What's strange is that other social sharing buttons, such as the FB like below follow the same syntax and are positioned perfectly.

```
.fb-like 
{
position: absolute; 
top:62px;
left:715px; 
}
```

Adding !important to the values does nothing, unfortunately.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please add what the `div` does currently.

Comment: Your styles may be overridden. Try to append `!important` to the values.

Comment: Good call @dop-trois as that might do it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When Google loads +1 button the `.g-plusone` class seems to disappear, so try to put this DIV inside another DIV, as illustrated below:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="google-button">

    <div class="g-plusone"></div>

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.google-button
{ 
position: absolute; 
top:95px;
left:715px; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for a very simple and elegant solution. I'm kicking myself for not thinking of it.

Comment: It happens =) Thanks for mark my answer as the best, it is my first one!

Answer (score 2):

After page loads, the Google div called **g-plusone** turns into a lot of code, but, you can manipulate this button with id generated.

In my case, for example, to align the button in the middle of the line I put:

```
 #___plusone_0{
    vertical-align: middle !important;
}
```

Note: The id **___plusone_0** is the id generated by the google codes. Do whatever you want with this id.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like Firebug to ensure you're targeting the correct element. The +1 button is very deeply nested, so you'll most likely need to look further up the DOM tree to get to it's outermost wrapper. You will be able to set the position of that without needing to use !important or anything, so I would definitely check this first.

Sorry, I would have just added this as a comment above but I don't seem to be able :)